# Island analysis using networkx in python environment social network analysis

Tags: python, graph, networkx, graph-theory, social-networking

I have a dataset from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/anshulmehtakaggl/github-organizations-social-network-analysis) where I am attempting to conduct a graph theory island analysis in python with networkx.
I am pretty new to python and graph theory.
The island analysis is the last part of what I am trying to accomplish.
i already calculated centrality measures and a graph of the network.
Below is the entire python code.
The dataset represents github groups and group members.
It's a bi-nodal dataset

```
`
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms import bipartite

url='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/greggmaloy/Data620/main/DATA_620_Assignment_1.csv'
data=pd.read_csv(url)
print(data)#.head(5))

# remove duplicates
# some member names were first name only or were 'none' 
df = data[~data.duplicated(keep=False)]
df = df[~df['member'].str.contains(r'[^a-zA-Z]', regex=True)]########comment out to run for entire dataset##########

#df = df.head(8000)
#df1=df['count']='1'
#grouped=df.groupby(['Organisation'])['count'].count()
#print(grouped)
#print(df1)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Organisation': df['Organisation'], 'Count': 1})
grouped = df1.groupby(['Organisation'])['Count'].count()
print(grouped)

merged_df = df.merge(grouped, on='Organisation', how='left')
print(merged_df)


graph=nx.Graph()
plt.show()
graph.add_nodes_from(merged_df['member']      ,bipartite=1, with_labels=False)
graph.add_nodes_from(merged_df['Organisation'],bipartite=0, with_labels=False)
node_colors = ['blue' if node_type == 1 else 'red' for node_type in nx.get_node_attributes(graph, 'bipartite').values()]

for i in range(len(df)):
  graph.add_edges_from([(df.iloc[i,1],df.iloc[i,0])])

plt.figure(figsize=(25,25))
plt.text(0.5, 1.05, "Github Organizations (red) and Members (blue)", fontsize=24, ha='center', transform=plt.gca().transAxes)
nx.draw_networkx(graph, with_labels=False, node_size=25,node_color=node_colors)
plt.show()

#delete duplicates
duplicates = merged_df.duplicated()


##centrality calulcations

# Set display options
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)


#centrality calculations

W  = bipartite.projected_graph(graph, merged_df['Organisation'])
C  = nx.closeness_centrality(W) 
B  = nx.betweenness_centrality(W) 
D  = nx.degree_centrality(W)
E  = nx.eigenvector_centrality(W)
#weighted
#W2 = bipartite.weighted_projected_graph(graph, df['Organisation'])
#C2  = nx.closeness_centrality(W2) 
#B2  = nx.betweenness_centrality(W2) 
#D2  = nx.degree(W2)
#E2  = nx.eigenvector_centrality(W2)
#degee_cent=nx.degree_centrality(df)


data = []
for w in merged_df['Organisation']:
    Organisation_degree = W.degree(w)
    #Friend_Meetings = W.degree(w, weight='weight')
    Closeness_value = C[w]
    #Closeness_value_weighted=C2[w]
    Betweeness=B[w]
    #Betweeness_weighted=B2[w]
    Degree=D[w]
    #Degree_weighted=D2[w]
    Eigenvector=E[w]
    #Eigenvector_weighted=E[w]
    
    data.append((w #Meetings_Attended
                 #,Friend_Meetings
                 ,Organisation_degree
                 ,Closeness_value#, Closeness_value_weighted      
                 ,Betweeness#, Betweeness_weighted
                 ,Degree#,Degree_weighted
                 ,Eigenvector#,Eigenvector_weighted
                ))

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Organisation"#,"Meetings Attended"
                                 # ,"# of Times Met w Friends"
                                 ,"Degree"
                                 ,"Closeness"#,"Closeness Centrality Weighted"
                                 ,"Betweenness"#,"Betweenness Centrality Weighted"
                                 ,"Degree_Cent"#,"Degree Centrality Weighted"
                                 ,"Eigenvector"#,"Eigenvector_weighted"
                                ]
                                )

#print(df1.to_string(index=False))

#final_df = merged_df.merge(df1, on=['Organisation','member'], how='left')


final_df = merged_df[['Count','Organisation']].merge(df1, on='Organisation', how='left')
final_df = final_df[[ 'Organisation', 'Degree','Count', 'Closeness', 'Betweenness', "Degree_Cent",'Eigenvector']]
final_df = final_df.drop_duplicates()
sorted_df = final_df.sort_values(by='Degree', ascending=False)
print(sorted_df)


###########island analysis starts here
def trim_edges(W, weight=1):
        g2=net.Graph()
        for f, to, edata in W.edges(data=True):
                if edata['?????????'] > weight:
                        g2.add_edge(f,to,edata)
        return g2
    
    
def island_method(W, iterations=5):
    weights= [edata['?????????'] for f,to,edata in W.edges(data=True)]

    mn=int(min(weights))
    mx=int(max(weights))
    #compute the size of the step, so we get a reasonable step in iterations
    step=int((mx-mn)/iterations)

    return [[threshold, trim_edges(W, threshold)] for threshold in range(mn,mx,step)]


cc = max(nx.connected_components(W), key=len)
largest_component = W.subgraph(cc)
islands = island_method(largest_component)


#islands = island_method(cc)
for i in islands:
    # print the threshold level, size of the graph, and number of connected components
    print(i[0], len(i[1]), len(list(nx.connected_components(i[1]))))
```

My questions are:

1. For the island analysis am I correct in using the projected partition 'W' since this is a bipartite data set?
   I believe so.
2. I believe the '?????' in the above island analysis references a weight.
   I was just going to use degree centrality for this to keep it simple.
   However, 'W' does not have degree centrality in it and I am wondering how I reference it as the weight?

Thanks for any assistance!

```
`

I get a lot of these types of errors because 'nodes' is not in 'W'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[218], line 22
     20 cc = max(nx.connected_components(W), key=len)
     21 largest_component = W.subgraph(cc)
---> 22 islands = island_method(largest_component)
     25 #islands = island_method(cc)
     26 for i in islands:
     27     # print the threshold level, size of the graph, and number of connected components

Cell In[218], line 10, in island_method(W, iterations)
      9 def island_method(W, iterations=5):
---> 10     weights= [edata['nodes'] for f,to,edata in W.edges(data=True)]
     12     mn=int(min(weights))
     13     mx=int(max(weights))

Cell In[218], line 10, in <listcomp>(.0)
      9 def island_method(W, iterations=5):
---> 10     weights= [edata['nodes'] for f,to,edata in W.edges(data=True)]
     12     mn=int(min(weights))
     13     mx=int(max(weights))

KeyError: 'nodes'`
```